# When wheat is harvested, does it drop 0 - 2 or 1 wheat?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm trying to decide whether to make a wheat or sugar cane farm. I want to know whether wheat drops 0 - 2 or 1 wheat when it is harvested. The wiki does not say.

Comment: Wheat and sugarcane are used for different things. You'll probably need both, not one or the other.

Comment: I am on a server with the ability to sell as stack of wheat for 2500 dollars and a stack of sugar cane for 3000 dollars. I have a 14 by 9 by 3 area to dedicate to a farm, so I'm wondering which I should do.

Comment: Without doing any math on it ... I would suggest that you go with the sugarcane farm. It grows ridiculously fast, and doesn't require anything for maintenance.

Comment: Does it grow any faster then wheat?

Comment: With sugar can you plant 1 block and 2 grow off of it, which lets you harvest 2 sugarcane. With wheat you plant a seed and it needs to go through all the growth stages (there are 8) before you can harvest 1 wheat. So while it may grow at the same rate, the time to be able to harvest 1 sugarcane vs 1 wheat would be a lot shorter.

Comment: Cane farms need a 4-block tall space plus a floor layer (because you have to have 1 layer for sand and water, a floor to hold up the sand, and it grows into the 3 blocks above the sand/water layer), so if you really only have 3 layers for the farm, you're stuck with wheat.

Comment: Can I place water adjacent to the sand/dirt and have it grow 2 blocks tall?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fully grown wheat drops 1 wheat, and 0-3 seeds when harvested. If it is not fully grown it only drops one seed.

[This is clearly stated on the wiki.](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Wheat_Seeds#Harvesting)

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, there are multiple articles dealing with wheat, so it is hard to find the one with the information I am looking for.

Comment: in his defense it is only clearly stated on the "Wheat Seeds" page, which is a little silly.

Comment: @Paralytic It's a wiki. I fixed it. :) It's now easy to find on the Wheat page as well.

Comment: @Yamikuronue nice!